# MVC 5 Windows Authentication logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I am trying to understand how to create MVC5 website with Active Directory authentication. Also I want to manage users. So for this I created a simple project in VS2013 and selected "Windows Authentication". When I run the application I get authentication popup to enter AD username and password. After that it does says on top right "Hello AD/UserName!".

But I am not seeing logic where it actually calls for authentication. Also I want to save few AD users to database and allow only them to login to website. How can I do this? Also how will my other web pages know whether user is already authenticated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

One Approach-

1. Instead of selecting 'Windows Authentication', you choose 'Anonymous' (doesn't remember exact word here)
2. Implement logic to Authenticate user against Active Directory. Once user is Authenticate, store that user object into 'User' property of Current Context. So that you can access it and authorised user in subsequent request.
3. As you are aware, AD can only authenticate user against it. Providing access to few of them is authorisation part which we need to handle as part of our application. Since you want to enable access to website for few people of AD, what you can do is add those users in your application's database and allow authorisation to those only.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. How can I store 'User' property of Current Context. Also I am not sure how to "Authenticate user against Active Directory". This is reason I am trying to find logic. Can you please put some code in your answer. It will be very help for beginners like me.

Comment: I am travelling currently. I have posted the answer through App. If you need some code sample then I can post that tomorrow.

Comment: Its **Form Authentication** not  'Anonymous'